# Crash in PyObject_Call

Tags: python

I'm writing a native Python module in C, and my call to `PyObject_Call` is crashing. The target is an instance method of an object, which was passed to my native object's constructor.

The constructor for my custom object type looks like this:

```c
static int InitMyThing(EventTapObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds) {
  char *kwlist[] = { "callback", NULL };

  if (!PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, kwds, "O", kwlist, &self->callback)) {
    return -1;
  }
  Py_INCREF(self->callback);
  ...
  return 0;
}
```

Later on, in response to an OS event (specifically, an OS X CGEventTap), I call `PyObject_CallObject(self->callback, NULL)`. This in turn will call `PyObject_Call`, which crashes.

I tried calling `PyObject_Call` directly (with an empty tuple, as prescribed), and that gets the same crash, as does `PyObject_Print`.

My native object isn't getting deleted in the mean time (at least, the destructor isn't getting called), and neither is the Python object that owns the callback method.

So if I'm calling `Py_INCREF` on the callback, how can it be going away?

Comment: When you say "I tried calling `PyObject_Call` directly… as does `PyObject_Print`", you mean you tried doing them in this function (in which case you can rule out refcounting as being at all relevant), or you tried doing them later on (in the CF callback, in which case refcounting could be relevant—and so could the GIL/threadstate and all kinds of other stuff)?

Comment: Also, what makes you think the problem is that the bound method's `self` object was destroyed, rather than any of the other things that could have gone wrong? Just that it seems most likely, or some evidence pointing to it?

Comment: Yeah, it was the GIL. Boy, I'm out of practice with these native module issues. You can post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I'm out of practice too. I try to write everything in Cython, or just use `ctypes` or `cffi` from Python. But some things were painful enough to debug that I still remember them…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't that the bound method's `self` object was destroyed, but that you're trying to call a Python function without holding the GIL.

That's usually the first thing to check when writing a C extension that executes code during asynchronous callbacks. You never know when CoreFoundation (or whatever) is going to call you…